# Are fairy and ferry exact homophones?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel-length

I was puzzled when a native speaker of American English (grown up in Texas) recently told me that they would pronounce *fairy* and *ferry* the same. I would expect a "long" vowel in fairy and a "short" vowel in ferry, partly because of the double consonant in the latter.

This concept of vowel length, which is important in my mother tongue German, is foreign to that speaker and confuses them. Merriam-Webster provides two possible pronunciations for [*ferry*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ferry), one of which is identical to the one for [*fairy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fairy), but their phonetic spelling doesn't seem to distinguish vowel lengths at all.

Obviously, given the heterogeneous English speaking community, there may not be one right answer at all; I'm interested in all accents and aspects.

Edit: Collins provides different pronunciations for [*fairy*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fairy) and [*ferry*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ferry); their audio samples come closer to how I would pronounce the words.

Comment: It depends where you've lived in your formative years. I pronounce *fairy/dairy, ferry/merry*, and *furry/hurry* all differently with respect to the vowel sound.

Comment: @DjinTonic Indeed, the vowel sound in *furry* is not at all the same as *hurry*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach M-W talks like me: ˈhər-ē /  ˈfər-ē

Comment: @DjinTonic: Maybe that's an AmE thing... I've never heard 'hurry' pronounced with the same vowel as 'furry'.

Comment: Collins agrees: fɜri / hɜri, hʌr-

Comment: Well, that's news to me!

Comment: OED: Brit. /ˈhʌri/, U.S. /ˈhəri/

Comment: This is called the [Mary-marry-merry merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mary%E2%80%93marry%E2%80%93merry_merger).  According to a study from 2003, 57% of American English speakers pronounced *Mary*, *marry*, and *merry* identically.

Comment: *Fairy* and *ferry* are different in a few parts of the U.S., including Philadelphia, New York City and New England. And in the U.S., when they differ, they generally differ not just in the length of the vowel but in the quality of the vowel, which explains why Merriam-Webster doesn't have any phonetic notation for vowel lengths. I don't know of any dialects that have phonemic vowel length in the U.S. (while I believe some dialects in England and Australia do.)

Comment: One of the difficulties for, say, Italian, learners of English is going from a language with just a few (basically five or seven for Italian) vowel sounds to the many in English: *lick, lack, look, luck, lake, like, leak* plus *lark lurk*. With just one such short word in a sentence, context is the key, but it can be most difficult with several such words in a sentence. Learners have to first learn to hear the differences.

Comment: @DjinTonic You mean pairwise different, i.e. fairy different from dairy? That's scary ;-). (Because Andrew responded with "indeed"....)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica No, pairs rhyme for me :-) Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I was referring to the question.

Comment: @Juhasz Well, the vowel *quality* is one thing, and I deliberately didn't mention it here. But I was more interested in the concept of vowel *length* and its possible application to this example.

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting. If you would care to elaborate a bit on the (missing) concept of vowel length in an answer I'd be grateful. The reaction of my native American speaker made me think that this is a fundamental difference between English and, say, German. I could also ask a more general question about it, focusing more on concepts than the specific example (or edit this one before an answer has appeared...).

Comment: Most varieties of English do not have phonemic vowel length.  We have allophonic variation in vowel length.  And like other allophonic features, most speakers are unaware of its existence.  Doubly confusing, we learn to read and write, we're taught about "long" and "short" vowels, but with a totally different meaning.  Kids are taught the "long e" sound, which is really /i/ (as in *feed*) and the "short e" sound, which is /ɛ/ (as in *fed*).  I'm not surprised that a native speaker was confused by this other sense of "long" and "short" vowels.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in comments, Modern English does not have vowel length. The so-called "long vowels" are modern descendants of the Middle English long vowels, which were changed by the Great Vowel Shift into tense vowels, no longer than any other. Unfortunately, this happened after the rules of English spelling got more or less fixed.

So the original difference between *fairy* and *ferry* was long/short vowel, which changed to tense/lax after the GVS. But in American English there was a further development. The distinction between tense and lax vowels tended to neutralize before /r/. So most Americans don't distinguish between /ir/ and /Ir/ (*here/hear*), or between /er/ and /Er/, so *ferry* and *fairy* are exact homonyms.

This is a regional variation; in Rhode Island, for example, one distinguishes *Mary, merry,* and *marry*, each with its own vowel.
But in the Midwest, where I come from, those are all homophonous.

Comment: Actually, [*here*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/here) and [*hear*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hear) are homophones even in British English. (I know you didn't say they weren't, but somebody reading your answer might infer they were.)

Comment: I dunno. In MA where I live Mary, merry and marry are all slightly different. Rhode Island must be like us. That said, if I hear someone making a difference between ferry and fairy, I'd say BrE for the ferry.

Comment: That distinction is peculiar to New England. Elsewhere in the US, /e/, /ɛ/, and /æ/ are all neutralized before /r/, like all the other tense/lax distinctions. /ir/ and /ɪr/, /ur/ and /ʊr/, and /or/ and /ɔr/ can't be distinguished in the midwest, any more than /er/. /ɛr/, and /ær/ are.

Answer (score 4):

Modern American English does not have phonemic vowel length. Americans, in fact, pay very little attention to vowel length, so it is quite difficult for them to learn to differentiate between long and short vowels in other languages. In American English, in the dialects that still preserve the difference between *fairy* and *ferry*, the difference is in the quality of the vowel: possibly /feri/ versus /fɛri/ (although different dialects will undoubtedly vary).

While this is somewhat controversial, I believe vowel length plays a role in modern British English. For an example of this, *Lexico* gives the current British pronunciations of [*bared*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bare?locale=en) and [*bed*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bed?locale=en) as [bɛːd] and [bɛd], differing only by vowel length; similarly, [*fairy*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fairy?locale=en) and [*ferry*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ferry?locale=en) also differ only in having [ɛː] and [ɛ].

*Bared* and *fairy* used to be pronounced the diphthong /ɛə/ in British English, and some British speakers, as well as some British dictionaries, still pronounce them that way. And while [ɛː] and [ɛ] are the only two vowels I know of that dictionaries give as differing only in length, I am convinced from listening to British speakers that some dialects also use length as the major differentiation between *beard* and *bid*; and between *cart* and *cut*.

Comment: After turning it over in my mind's ear a few times, I got ***very very*** confused trying to compare *I **vary very** few aspects of my diction according to who I'm conversing with, and my vowels aren't **very varied** anyway*. It's worse than Peter Piper and that pesky pack of pickled peppers!

Answer (score 1):

I must agree, I grew up in Rhode Island and my Boyfriend grew up in Texas. We now live in Iowa. We argue frequently about how to pronounce ferry and fairy and other words as well. To your point above about distinguishing based on the vowel. That is absolutely something I was taught as a child. It gets fun too because his mom is an English professor from South Carolina. All in all, just wanted to let you know you’re absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In a [dialect survey](http://dialect.redlog.net/staticmaps/q_15.html) participants were asked how they pronounced Mary [same vowel as in fairy] /merry [same vowel as in ferry]/marry.

The answers showed that the majority made no distinction: